# Fill gap between date using resample (multi-index)

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have a dataframe with gaps between date.

[image: Dataframe]

It`s necessary to groupby the first 2 columns of this dataframe and then fill the gaps.

What I am trying is this:

```
df.groupby(['cod_interno', 'unidade_lojas', 'data']).apply(lambda x : x.resample('D').ffill()).reset_index(level=0,drop=True)
```

However I got this error message:

> TypeError: Only valid with DatetimeIndex, TimedeltaIndex or PeriodIndex, but got an instance of 'Int64Index'

Is there a better approach to solve this ?

I tried this approach [Resampling a multi-index DataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15617496/resampling-a-multi-index-dataframe), but I not so familiar with 'stack()'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you can use [`DataFrame.set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) with column `data` with datetimes and then use `resample` after `groupby`, `lambda` function is not necessary:

```
df.set_index('data').groupby(['cod_interno', 'unidade_lojas']).resample('D').ffill()
```